# Create download page from post option link

Tags: custom-field, page-template

I have a button download. It's contain the link from post option. I want to when click button download, it will show a download page with the link in post option instead go direct link from it.

Please help me !
[image: The link download in post option]

[image: The single post page with download button]

[image: The page i want to show download link when customer click download button]

Comment: As formulated this feels a little "do this for me for free". How exactly is that link implemented? What you want that "page to be" - one page in general, page for _each_ download, something else? What had you tried already and how far you got?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain, but I think you are looking to use this plugin or one like it.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/

You should be able to create free download pages for no cost to your users.

Another option would be to just use a second page. In post option "Download Link" box, put the link of another WP page that you would create. Then on that page, have the actual download link formatted how you would want.

Cheers!